# Can't able to deploy EAR on JBoss 8 WildFly

Tags: java, jboss

I tried to deploy an EAR file into the JBoss WildFly server, but it is not deploying the EAR file.

Steps that I followed:

1. Copy the EAR file and paste into `jboss_dir/standalone/deployments` location.
2. Run the command `jboss_dir/bin/standalone.bat`

If I put the JAR or WAR file than JBoss server can able to deploy.

Kindly help me out to fix this issue.

In JBoss 4.2 I just copy EAR file into the `default/deploy` folder and it is able to deploy, but I want to deploy EAR file into JBoss WildFly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the `application.xml` deployment descriptor in META-INF inside the ear.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<application version="7" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee">

<display-name>Your-ear-name</display-name>   

 <module>   
   <java>Your-jar-1</java>
 </module>
 <module>    
   <java>Your-jar-2</java>    
 </module>

<library-directory>lib</library-directory> 

</application>
```